# USB 3.0 on Dell Inspiron 15 5000 Series

Tags: windows-7, dell-inspiron, usb-3

I have a 32GB Kingston Datatraveler G4 and Inspiron i5 5999 but the data transfer  is still slow. A sample test is here:[image]

Do i need to install some extra drivers for Inspiron 5559?